# Why don't scripts run when added with Chrome's "Edit as HTML" feature?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Why does this work when run in Chrome's Developer Tools (Console Tab):

```
var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
script.type = 'text/javascript'; 
script.src ='somescript.js'; 
$0.appendChild(script);
```

but this not work when added as a string using the Edit As HTML feature in Chrome's Developer Tools (Elements tab, editing `body` tag):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="somescript.js"></script>
```

?

Contents of `somescript.js`:

```
console.log('some js is being run');
```

Defintion of "work" in this case:

`some js is being run` is printed as console output

Comment: @Oriol Why don't you point to the duplicate question since you're certain it exists?

Comment: Woops, I didn't see the "This question already has an answer here: ..." part with the referenced duplicate until I scrolled up, my apologies.

Comment: In short, Chrome's "edit as HTML" uses `innerHTML`, and that does parse `<script>` as DOM elements but does not run them, as explained in [Can scripts be inserted with innerHTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1197575/1529630)